# Derivatives of a vector and its transpose

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Assuming that $f(x)=x^Tx-k^2=0$ holds for some $k$ and vector $x$, is it possible to derive that
$$
u \nabla f = uIx
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $u$ is a lagrange multiplier?

If I simply derive $f$ with respect to $x$, I get
$$
u\left( Ix + x^T\right)
$$
where I use that $\frac{d}{dx}x^T=I$, but it gives me that annoying extra term $ux^T$. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or missing a trick where you can somehow ignore the last term.

I'm a bit insecure in all of this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $df =dx^{T}x+ x^{T}dx = 2x^{T}dx \implies f'(x) = 2x^{T}$. Hence, $\nabla f = 2x$. I don't know how your derived expression is possible.

Comment: @AlexSilva How do you get $df=dx^Tx+x^Tdx$ ? I would have thought we can apply the product rule and get $\frac{df}{dx}=x+x^T$. If I do it component-wise, I get $f'(x)=2x$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $u\left( Ix + x^T\right)$ is definately incorrect because of incompatible vector dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that almost every discussion about matrix calculus hinges on the conventions you choose. The conventions I'll use here are:

1. $x$ is a column vector
2. The derivative of a scalar with respect to a column vector is a row vector and viceveresa.
3. The gradient is a column vector, ie $\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{T}}$.

This has various consequences:

1. If $\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x}$ is at the left of a column vector, it transposes it to a row vector.
2. If $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{T}}$ is at the right of a row vector, it transposes it to a column vector.
3. $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x^{T}} = I$

Then if we start with your expression
$$f(x) = x^{T}x - k^{2}$$
and we want to get its gradient $\nabla f$, we get
$$\nabla f(x)
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{T}}(x)
= \frac{\partial (x^{T}x)}{\partial x^{T}}\\
= \frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x^{T}}x + x^{T}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{T}}
=x + x = 2x$$

From this, we immediately have

$$u\nabla f(x) = 2ux$$

so I don't know howw you arrived to

> $$u\nabla f(x) = uIx = ux$$

It would be helpful if you gave context for where did you find or how you derived it.